# Is VIEW SERVER STATE required for VIEW DATABASE STATE?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get permission to VIEW DATABASE STATE so I can view the activity monitor for any blocks on a certain database.

I'm being told by our IT department that I cannot have this because it requires VIEW SERVER STATE before they can give me VIEW DATABASE STATE.  Is this really the case?  Or is it possible to give VIEW DATABASE STATE on a single DB?

Thanks.

Comment: You can get `VIEW DATABASE STATE` without getting `VIEW SERVER STATE`, but most of the things you want to monitor in Activity Monitor do in fact require `VIEW SERVER STATE` because SQL Server doesn't really partition resources per database.

Comment: Would just having VIEW DATABASE STATE show me blocks?